# LWC radioGroup hide option labels

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, radio-button, lightning-radiogroup

I'm struggling with the radiogroup lwc. I only want to display the radio button, I don't want to display the option's label and I want my radio button to be centered in it's div.
The only thing I managed to do so far is to set a label value to '' so that no text appears. But a span for this value is still integrated in the DOM, and thus my radio buttons are not perfectly centered in their div.

[image]

Html :

[image]

And this is how I setted the label value in JS :

```
results = [
    {"mao": "REYNAUD Jeanne", "loc": "MARSEILLE (13012)", "code":"BAR-TH-104","action":"#123456","statut":"Validé instructeur", options:[{label:'', value: '#123456'}]},
    {"mao": "CHIAPALE Basile", "loc": "MARSEILLE (13012)", "code":"Bar-EN-101","action":"#666953","statut":"Rejet", options:[{label:'', value: '#666953'}]},
    {"mao": "CHIAPALE Basile", "loc": "MARSEILLE (13012)", "code":"Bar-TH-123","action":"#254812","statut":"OK dépôt", options:[{label:'', value: '#254812'}]}

];
```

I tried to override the css proporties of the span that bothers me in the DOM with a "display:none" property but I can't access it.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this? Or if it is even possible to hide the option label?